# Print as you type in Ajax using python

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views, ajaxform

**Problem Statement:** 
*As we **type in the text box** it has to **display exactly the same text** that is entered in the text field in the index.html file **without clicking submit button using Ajax***

To do this I have coded in this way shown below:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>Submit after typing finished</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    $('#search-input').keyup(function (event) {
    var query =($('#search-input').val());
    if (query != '' || query != ' ') {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/ajaxmssql/XViews.py",
    data: {
    'q': query
    },
    dataType: "html",

    success: function(data) 
    {
            var params = $(html).filter(function(){ return $(this).is('p') });
            params.each(
                function()
                {
                    var value = "<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>";
                    $("#main-results-search").append( value );
                }
            );
    },
    error: function(request, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                $("#debug").html(request.responseText);
                $("#debug").html("Could Not Print from Server Side Script");
            }

    });

    }

    });

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Printing...</h1>
<input type="search" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="search-input" placeholder="Type to print ..."/>

 <div id="main-results-search"></div>

 <div id = "debug"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

**XViews.py**

```
#!C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

def print_header():
    print("""Content-type: text/html\n
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>""")

def print_close():
    print ("""</body>
    </html>""")

def display_error():
    print_header()
    print ("<p>An Error occurred parsing the parameters passed to this script.</p>")
    print_close()


def main():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    search = form.getvalue('search-input')
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query is not None and query != '' and request.is_ajax():
        print ("<p>This is from query</p>")
    if search is not None and search != '' and request.is_ajax():
        print ("<p>This is from search</p>")
    # if "search" in form:
    #     print_header()
    #     print("<h2>Entered Text %s %s</h2>" % (search))
    #     print_close()
    # else:
    #     display_error()


main()
```

**Output Result**: But whenever I type any text characters it displays **Could Not Print** than the expected result?

Comment: log `request, ajaxOptions, thrownError` these to the console, and show us the result

Comment: Apart from anything else, you need two line breaks between the header and the HTML, not one.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I'm not getting what you are trying to say now. Those two line breaks is it in .html or .py file

Comment: Forget that, you do have two line breaks. But what makes you think your condition `if 'search' in form` would ever evaluate to true? The only parameter you send in your Ajax request is `q`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  
Hi Sir, 
I have edited my post. Please try to read b/w the lines. 
Instead of printing **This is from query**. It displays
**Could Not Print from Server Side Script**

Comment: What is `request` supposed to be in the updated code? Where is it coming from?